# grepl matching strictly only certain parts of words

Tags: r, grepl

I need to know if there exists a solution.

Let's say that we have a list that contains as follows:

```
id Item
1  "CRANBERRY 10PKTS CARTON, BLUEBERRY 20PKTS CARTON"
2  "CRANBERRY 10PKTS CARTON,BLUEBERRY 20PKTS CARTON"
3  "CRANBERRY 10PKTS CARTON"
4  "CRANBERRY 30PKTS CARTON"
```

What I would like is to match for only "CRANBERRY" and its associated names. The crux here is when something like id1 is present, grepl should return a false, since it not only contains cranberry, but has blueberry as well.

Is there a way for grepl to return false for id1 and id2, but true for id3 and id4? Preferably, a single grepl sentence is all that's needed for the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the example, the pattern seems to be that the words 'CRANBERRY', 'BLUEBERRY' etc. occurs once in each set of words separated by a `,`.  If that is the case, we can match the word 'CRANBERRY' in a sentence from the start of the string (`^`) followed by characters that are not a `,` (`[^,]+`) until the end of the string (`$`)

```
grepl("^.*\\bCRANBERRY[^,]+$", df1$Item)
#[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Comment: I think i understand the beginning, but not the []. Does the [] here serves as a 'attachment' or sorts that the grepl can see?

Comment: @bzzbzzRzzbzz  Inside the `[]`, we use the `^,` to match one or more (`+`) characters that are not  a `,`.  So basicallly, we are removing the possibility of other words such as `BLUEBERRY` etc based on the example showed